# Java Set to Object[][]

Tags: java, lambda, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a `Set<String>` that I'd like to use for a TestNG parameterized test.

I want to go from `<"a", "b", "c">` to `{{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}}`

I've tried:

```
Set<String> elements = Stream.of("a", "b", "c").collect(Collectors.toSet());

Object[][] elementsArray = (Object[][]) elements.stream()
                .map(t -> new Object[] {t})
                .toArray(Object[]::new);
```

but it doesn't work. Any pointers on how to achieve this? Non-lambda solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `Object[][]::new` instead:

```
Set<String> elements = Stream.of("a", "b", "c").collect(Collectors.toSet());

Object[][] elementsArray = elements.stream()
                .map(t -> new Object[] {t})
                .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

With `Object[]::new` you're creating an `Object[]` and then casting it to an `Object[][]` (which will fail).

Answer (score 4):

You did everything right except the method reference to create the `Object[][]`.  You're constructing a 2D-array with 1D-array elements holding the strings.

Change

```
Object[]::new
```

to

```
Object[][]::new
```

Once this is done, then you don't need the cast to `Object[][]`; remove that as well.